# Detect drag cancellation in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can achieve cancellation detecting in vanilla js by using code below.

```
el.addEventListener('dragend', event => {
  let cancelled = event.dataTransfer.dropEffect === 'none';
  if(cancelled) {
    // do something when drag cancelled.
  }
}, false);
```

but I failed when trying to convert this snippet to a jQuery version since jQuery wrapped the event into a jQuery event which doesn't own dataTransfer property.

```
el.on('dragend', event => {
  console.log(event.dataTransfer); // => undefined
});
```

I wonder how can I detect drag cancellation with jQuery.
By the way, I'm not using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) but I'd like to try if things would become easier with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.originalEvent` property of jQuery event to get `.dataTransfer` property

```js
$("div")
.on("dragend", function(e) {
  console.log(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer)
})
```

```css
div {
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 8px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div draggable>drag</div>
<div droppable>drop</div>
```

Comment: Great, didn't find `originalEvent` at first sight.